# Rank of Jacobian does not depend on the choice of polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field, $A := k[x_1, \dots x_n]$ and $I = (f_1, \dots f_m) \subseteq A$, and fix a prime ideal $I \subseteq \mathfrak{p}$.
For any polynomial $q \in A$, define $q(\mathfrak{p}) := q \;\mathrm{mod.} \;\mathfrak{p}A_{\mathfrak{p}}$, where $A_\mathfrak{p}$ is the localization of $A$ at $\mathfrak{p}$.

Now let $p_1, \dots p_r \in A$ be polynomials and define $J(\mathfrak{p}) := \left(\frac{\partial p_i}{\partial x_j}(\mathfrak{p})\right)_{i=1, \dots r, j = 1, \dots n} \in M_{r\times n}(\kappa(\mathfrak{p}))$, where $\kappa(\mathfrak{p}) \cong A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}A_{\mathfrak{p}}$. Suppose $q_1, \dots q_r \in A$ are other polynomials with $q_i = p_i \; \mathrm{mod.} \; I$, and let $J'(\mathfrak{p}) =  \left(\frac{\partial q_i}{\partial x_j}(\mathfrak{p})\right)_{i=1, \dots r, j = 1, \dots n}$.

**My question is: is it true that $J(\mathfrak{p})$ has maximum rank if and only if $J'(\mathfrak{p})$ does?**

If we restrict to $r = 1$, then $J(\mathfrak{p})$ has maximum rank if and only if $\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_j} \notin \mathfrak{p}A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ for some $j \leq n$, and similarly $J'(\mathfrak{p})$ has maximum rank if and only if $\frac{\partial q}{\partial x_j} \notin \mathfrak{p}A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ for some $j \leq n$. If we write $$q = p + h_1f_1 + \dots + h_mf_m$$
then this boils down to showing that $\frac{\partial q}{\partial x_i} \notin \mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}$ for some $i$ if and only if $\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i} + \sum_{j=1}^{m} h_j \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i} \notin \mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}$ for some (possibly other) $i$, since the derivatives of $h_j$ are multiplied by the $f_j$ and hence killed modulo $\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: This is false as you've written it down currently - consider $A=k[x]$, $I=(x)$, and $p=x$. Then the Jacobian matrix is $1$ in this scenario, but letting $q=0$ (which agrees with $p$ modulo $I$) we find that the Jacobian matrix is $0$. What's the motivation for this problem?

Comment: I am working with maps of affine $k$-schemes of finite type $V \to \mathbb{A}^n$ where $k$ is not necessarily algebraically closed, and I would like to rephrase being étale at a point using the (non-)vanishing of minors of a Jacobian. I know of a sufficient condition, but I miss a necessary one. Following https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4136445/relationship-between-%c3%a9tale-maps-and-polynomials, I might be able to do it if $V = \mathbb{A}^n$, but I'm not sure of what to do for a general (affine) $V$.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for condition (8) of [Stacks 02GU](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02GU).

Comment: That's useful, but I was wondering if there was a way to associate some polynomials “canonically” to a morphism $V \to \mathbb{A}^n$, the way you would do for a morphism $\mathbb{A}^n \to \mathbb{A}^n$, so that I need only check their Jacobian instead of “some” Jacobian (btw, this is why I was trying to prove that rank is independent on the choice of representatives modulo $I$, to be able to check étaleness on a Jacobian of my choice.)